# how I can get the ID of the selected option from a dynamically created dropdown using PHP, or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic, dropdown

I use this code in fetching the data from the database.

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM employee");
```

And then render like bellow:

```
            <select name="employees">
                <option value="">Select Employee</option>
                <?php while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $employee_name = $rows['firstname'] . " " . $rows['lastname'];
                    echo "<option id = emprecord_id value = '$employee_name'>$employee_name</option>";
                }  
            ?>
        </select>
```

I need to know how can I get the ID (or if there is anyway) of the selected value because I will insert values for the selected option in another table.
Like i get the data from the employee table and If the Name of the employee was selected, it will proceed to another page we're I will insert new data for its payroll.

Comment: You need to put the employee ID in the `value` attribute of the `<option>`. Then it will be sent to the server/PHP when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the selected option with **selectedIndex** :

```
let tSelectedIndex = document.querySelector('select[name=languages]').selectedIndex;
let tID = document.querySelectorAll('select[name=languages] option')[tSelectedIndex].id;
```